# asymmetric errors with exponential

Tags: siunitx

I'm using `siunitx`, but I don't see how to put an asymmetric error, like this one, in text nor in a `tabular` environment:

```
$\left( 1.09^{+0.28}_{-0.23} \right) \times 10^{-3}$
```

Is there a way with `siunitx`?

Comment: Not a direct solution to your question, but a suggestion: Could you report the (now symmetric) standard errors of the *log-transformed* variables?

Comment: @Mico well, mine was a general question on a quite common way to print measurements with asymmetric errors. I would like to use that form and not to change the way we write them :)

Answer (score 5):

## Current answer

This feature is planned for v3.3, due for release shortly. The current input interface is `1.09(28:23)`, i.e. a 'compact' form, although other formats may be introduced over time.

---

## Historical answer

Currently, the answer is 'no', as `siunitx` doesn't support this format. The package understands '[standard uncertainties](http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Info/Constants/definitions.html)', which are necessarily symmetrical. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/24) covering asymmetrical uncertainties/tolerances, but at present I don't really have a good method to handle these. (A sensible interface is pretty hard to come up with, for a start.)